# Adding a timer to giveaway command discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I was trying to create a discord bot with giveaway command which updates time left every 1-2 mins in giveaway embed . I have been trying it since 3 days but wasn't able to find a solution. I managed to make it update seconds, but if I specify time more than 1m i.e. 60 seconds it automatically converts it to seconds and starts giveaway with time left in **just seconds** . I want it to keep time in given unit and  update time in --days, --hours, --minutes, --seconds left.

Here are a few images what i mean:

What it currently do:

[image]

What i want it to do:

[image]

Its just Ends In Or Time remaining what i want to be changed!

My current code:

```py
@commands.command()
    @commands.guild_only()
    async def gstart(self, ctx, duration, *, prize):
        time = self.convert(duration)
        if time == -1:
            await ctx.send(f'Answer Time With A Proper Unit (s, m, h, d)')
            return
        elif time == -2:
            await ctx.send(f'Time Must Be A Integer!')
            return
        giveawayembed = discord.Embed(
            title=" New Giveaway! ",
            description=f"**Prize:** {prize}\n"
                        f"**Hosted By:** {ctx.author.mention}\n"
                        f"**Ends In:** {time} Seconds",
            colour=discord.Color.green()
        )

        msg = await ctx.send(embed=giveawayembed)

        reactions = await msg.add_reaction("")

        while time:
            await sleep(10)
            time -= 10
            giveawayembed.description= f"**Prize:** {prize}\n**Hosted By:** {ctx.author.mention}\n**Ends In:** {time} Seconds"
            await msg.edit(embed=giveawayembed)

        new_msg = await ctx.fetch_message(msg.id)

        users = await new_msg.reactions[0].users().flatten()
        users.pop(users.index(self.client.user))

        winner = random.choice(users)

        endembed = discord.Embed(
            title="Giveaway ended!",
            description=f"Prize: {prize}\nWinner: {winner.mention}")

        await msg.edit(embed=endembed)
        await ctx.send(f" Giveaway Winner: {winner.mention} | Prize: {prize}")
```

For Converting Time I Have:

```py
class Giveaway(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    def convert(self, time):
        pos = ["s", "m", "h", "d"]
        time_dict = {"s" : 1, "m" : 60, "h" : 3600, "d" : 3600*24}
        unit = time[-1]

        if unit not in pos:
            return -1
        try:
            val = int(time[:-1])
        except:
            return -2

        return val * time_dict[unit]
```

Any help is highly appreciated! 
And I m sorry if I wasn't able to make you understand my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your problem as it is actually a very simple fix, you can either import time, or use `await asyncio.sleep(time)`

Before using the code I am providing, make sure to `import asyncio` in your imports.

Your code:

```py
    @commands.command()
    @commands.guild_only()
    async def gstart(self, ctx, duration, *, prize):
        time = self.convert(duration)
        if time == -1:
            await ctx.send(f'Answer Time With A Proper Unit (s, m, h, d)')
            return
        elif time == -2:
            await ctx.send(f'Time Must Be A Integer!')
            return
        giveawayembed = discord.Embed(
            title=" New Giveaway! ",
            description=f"**Prize:** {prize}\n"
                        f"**Hosted By:** {ctx.author.mention}\n"
                        f"**Ends In:** {time} Seconds",
            colour=discord.Color.green()
        )

        msg = await ctx.send(embed=giveawayembed)

        reactions = await msg.add_reaction("")

        while time:
            await sleep(10)
            time -= 10
            giveawayembed.description= f"**Prize:** {prize}\n**Hosted By:** {ctx.author.mention}\n**Ends In:** {time} Seconds"
            await msg.edit(embed=giveawayembed)

        new_msg = await ctx.fetch_message(msg.id)

        users = await new_msg.reactions[0].users().flatten()
        users.pop(users.index(self.client.user))

        winner = random.choice(users)

        endembed = discord.Embed(
            title="Giveaway ended!",
            description=f"Prize: {prize}\nWinner: {winner.mention}")

        await msg.edit(embed=endembed)
        await ctx.send(f" Giveaway Winner: {winner.mention} | Prize: {prize}")
```

In both fixes I will fix a slight problem that could easily be fixed, you have it so while time, it will go down by 10, I recommend doing it so it says `while time > 0:` so that once it hits 0 it wont keep counting down.

Easy fix using `await asyncio.sleep(time)`:

```py
    @commands.command()
    @commands.guild_only()
    async def gstart(self, ctx, duration, *, prize):
        time = self.convert(duration)
        if time == -1:
            await ctx.send(f'Answer Time With A Proper Unit (s, m, h, d)')
            return
        elif time == -2:
            await ctx.send(f'Time Must Be A Integer!')
            return
        giveawayembed = discord.Embed(
            title=" New Giveaway! ",
            description=f"**Prize:** {prize}\n"
                        f"**Hosted By:** {ctx.author.mention}\n"
                        f"**Ends In:** {time} Seconds",
            colour=discord.Color.green()
        )

        msg = await ctx.send(embed=giveawayembed)

        reactions = await msg.add_reaction("")

                while time >= 0:
            if time <= 60:
                giveaway.remove_field(index=1)
                giveaway.insert_field_at(index=1, name='Ends:', value=f'{time} second(s) from now')
                await my_msg.edit(embed=giveaway)
                time -= 10
                await asyncio.sleep(10)
            elif 60 <= time < 3600:
                giveaway.remove_field(index=1)
                giveaway.insert_field_at(index=1, name='Ends:', value=f'{time/60} minute(s) from now')
                await my_msg.edit(embed=giveaway)
                time -= 6
                await asyncio.sleep(6)
            elif 3600 <= time < 86400:
                giveaway.remove_field(index=1)
                giveaway.insert_field_at(index=1, name='Ends:', value=f'{time/3600} hour(s) from now')
                await my_msg.edit(embed=giveaway)
                time -= 360
                await asyncio.sleep(360)
            elif time >= 86400:
                giveaway.remove_field(index=1)
                giveaway.insert_field_at(index=1, name='Ends:', value=f'{time/86400} day(s) from now')
                await my_msg.edit(embed=giveaway)
                time -= 8640
                await asyncio.sleep(8640)
        if time <= 0:
            giveaway.remove_field(index=1)
            giveaway.insert_field_at(index=1, name='Ends:', value=f'Ended at {datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%B %d, %I:%M %p")}') # noqa
            await my_msg.edit(embed=giveaway)

        await asyncio.sleep(time)

        new_msg = await ctx.fetch_message(msg.id)

        users = await new_msg.reactions[0].users().flatten()
        users.pop(users.index(self.client.user))

        winner = random.choice(users)

        endembed = discord.Embed(
            title="Giveaway ended!",
            description=f"Prize: {prize}\nWinner: {winner.mention}")

        await msg.edit(embed=endembed)
        await ctx.send(f" Giveaway Winner: {winner.mention} | Prize: {prize}")
```

If you are still confused or have any more questions you can contact me on discord at `killrebeest#7187` or comment on this answer. Have a good day!

Comment: it still converted it in seconds and the timer again starts in Seconds. I want it to show timer like: if i enter 2m(minutes) it would should in embed as 2m and passes time like ...
1m 50s ....1m 30s,,,,1m 10.... and not to convert it in seconds like 120 seconds ...and not ...120s....100s...80s...

Comment: @Nucleo__ I just edited it, try that! Sorry also, I've been away from my computer.